# Is it possible to absolutely prevent deletion of Objects (and objects) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deno

While it's possible to prevent deletion of Object properties by using freeze/seal/preventExtensions, I'd love to know whether it's possible to prevent deleting the object itself.

For example, in case I create an object in the global scope, and want to avoid nested functions or other modules from being able to delete that object, can I treat this global-scoped object simply as a property of the globalThis variable? Would it be possible to prevent deleting it in all hosts - Node, browsers, Deno?

My final goal is that, basically, I want to prevent overriding the object, rename it's properties/fields/symbols, or modifying it's values, or manipulating it's prototype chain as well.

So, please tell me how to keep this secret unchanged, undeleted (and maybe un-readable) along with all of it's fields and sub-fields:

```
const secretTree = {
  name: 'barack obama',
  password: 'ilovetrump',
  subTrusts: [
    { name: 'biden', password: 'zZzZ' }
  ]
};

(function putin() {
  delete secretTree;
  globalThis.secretTree = { name: 'vlad', password: '123456' };
})();

// and also this:
// delete secretTree; const secretTree = ...
// and all other variations of deletion
```

Please, treat the case of null-prototyped object as well (in which `__proto__: null`).

Maybe, the correct way to approach this question and to describe it, is that we need to protect the "variable" itself from changing, as opposed to protect the "object" value inside it.  To say, I want to "reserve" the variable name from any modifications, so forever I know that "globalThis.secretTree" will refer to something I trust on.

I tried to avoid some untrusted library functions from touching important objects.

Comment: You can't programmatically delete objects in JS, only Garbage Collector can. With [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator you can remove keys from objects (it doesn't delete the assigned value from the memory), it's not possible to delete variables with the said operator.

Comment: @Teemu But objects are keys of other objects in their turn as well, aren't they? For example, some global object is also a "key" inside the globalThis object. Also, when I say "to delete object", I mean any kind of operation that brings the object into the stage of removing by the garbage-collector, for example, assigning "null" to the last reference to an object, is similar to deletion in my terminology (and as far as I understand, also in JS in general, but maybe not)

Comment: In my code example, in case it doesn't work, I want to solve this: "delete globalThis.secretTree" which of course should work, since it's a key/field and not the object itself

Comment: Also, Mozilla's MDN claims it's possible: "While delete identifier may work if identifier refers to a configurable property of the global object, you should avoid this form and prefix it with globalThis instead.", and it's an issue of strict-mode, here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Global variables declared with `let` or `const` are not properties of `window`, there's no way to delete such variables. Use `const` to declare a variable which you can't set to `null`.  If there's another reference to object's property value, it's not removed even by GC. And, global namespace is never garbage collected, that's one of the biggest reasons why you should avoid global variables. Simply use modules to encapsulate your objects.

Comment: From what I read, this seems motivated by the desire to hide data in JavaScript runtime code. If so, be cautioned: that's not possible — all values in every scope, module, etc. can be inspected in a debugger at runtime.

Comment: @jsejcksn Please assume no external tools (like debugger), but just the JS Runtime scope/context

Comment: @Teemu Window is for browsers isn't it? What is the general approach and is it always true?

Comment: V8 JS engine is used in many browsers and in nodejs. All you need was said in my last comment, use modules and `const`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: `Object.defineProperty()` with `Object.freeze()`

You can use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (or [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) or [`Reflect.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/defineProperty)):

> By default, properties added using `Object.defineProperty()` are not writable, not enumerable, and not configurable.

You can also use [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) to freeze nested objects to make immutable structures.

Example:

```js
Object.defineProperty(globalThis, "secretTree", {
  value: Object.freeze({
    name: "barack obama",
    password: "ilovetrump",
    subTrusts: Object.freeze([
      Object.freeze({ name: "biden", password: "zZzZ" }),
    ]),
  }),
});
```

Attempts to modify the data will fail silently or throw errors.

#### Option 2: Modules

Variables defined inside an ES module are scoped to that module. Code outside the module cannot get nor delete its data unless the module exports a reference to it.

example.mjs

```
export {}; // a module must have at least one `export` or `import`

const secretTree = { /* your data */ };
```

Other code attempting to access, modify, or delete it will fail to do so:

```js
import * as data from "./example.mjs";

delete data.secretTree; // doesn't reference the actual `secretTree`
```